# How can I filter a table to return only an equal number of rows based on a positive and negative value?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to eliminate the last row in the result set (doesn't necessarily have to be the last row).

Am I able to filter the table so it only returns a row if it has a matching row with the opposite itemamt value?

For example, I only want rows that have itemamt -1000 AND another row with 1000. Since there are three rows with the positive 1000, I'd want to eliminate only one of those rows (doesn't matter which one).

[image]

Comment: didn't you just ask this question 10 mins ago?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793251/sql-how-can-i-eliminate-last-row  unfortunately I'm out of downvotes

Comment: You figured you need a better explanation....are you going to post it soon? The problem here is that we have no idea what you are really trying to do and the explanation is not clear. Do you not have anything in your table that identifies a row? What you posted is a bunch of duplicate data. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: it is duplicate data, the only differentiation is the item# (which doesn't matter) and the itemamt.

Comment: Use a CTE, and drop in a `ROW_NUMBER()` partitioned by the amount.  Then join the positives and negatives to one another on the amount/row#

Comment: @JiggsJedi ha!   I started to write exactly that for an answer, and then I realized that it would take a UNION instead of a JOIN to get the desired results, but yeah.

Comment: @TabAlleman I got the same results you did -- ps. you're missing FROMs in your CTE def's.

Comment: told ya it was quick and dirty... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution.  Separate the positives from the negatives in their own CTEs with Row_Numbers and use the row numbers to get only matched pairs:

```
    DECLARE @Test TABLE (VENDID VARCHAR(10), INVOICE INT, EXPPED INT, ITEM INT, REF VARCHAR(10), ENTITYID INT, ACCTNUM BIGINT, ITEMAMOUNT MONEY)
INSERT INTO @Test 
VALUES ('ABC123',12345,'201102',1,'QWERTY',200, 9876543232, 1000),
       ('ABC123',12345,'201102',2,'QWERTY',200, 9876543232, -1000),
       ('ABC123',12345,'201102',3,'QWERTY',200, 9876543232, 1000),
       ('ABC123',12345,'201102',4,'QWERTY',200, 9876543232, -1000),
       ('ABC123',12345,'201102',5,'QWERTY',200, 9876543232, 1000)

;WITH cteP AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ItemAmount] ORDER BY [Item] ASC) AS rn
  from @Test
  WHERE ITEMAMOUNT>0
),
cteN AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ItemAmount] ORDER BY [Item] ASC) AS rn
  from @Test
  WHERE ITEMAMOUNT<0
)
SELECT * FROM cteP
WHERE cteP.rn IN (SELECT rn FROM cteN WHERE cteN.ItemAmount = cteP.ItemAmount * -1)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cteN
WHERE cteN.rn IN (SELECT rn FROM cteP WHERE cteN.ItemAmount = cteP.ItemAmount * -1)
ORDER BY [Item] ASC
```

This is a little quick and dirty.  It can be further improved by replacing the `*` with column lists and using `EXISTS()` instead of `IN()`

Comment: Further improved to allow for varying ItemAmounts.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (VENDID VARCHAR(10), INVOICE INT, EXPPED INT, ITEM INT, REF VARCHAR(10), ENTITYID INT, ACCTNUM BIGINT, ITEMAMOUNT MONEY)
INSERT INTO @Test 
VALUES ('ABC123',12345,'201102',1,'QWERTY',200, 9876543232, 1000),
       ('ABC123',12345,'201102',2,'QWERTY',200, 9876543232, -1000),
       ('ABC123',12345,'201102',3,'QWERTY',200, 9876543232, 1000),
       ('ABC123',12345,'201102',4,'QWERTY',200, 9876543232, -1000),
       ('ABC123',12345,'201102',5,'QWERTY',200, 9876543232, 1000)

;WITH X AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INVOICE,ITEMAMOUNT ORDER BY ITEM) AS RN
    FROM @Test
)

SELECT X1.*
FROM X X1
JOIN X X2 ON X1.INVOICE=X2.INVOICE AND X2.ITEMAMOUNT<0 AND X1.RN=X2.RN
WHERE X1.ITEM>0
```